# Publishing Web Controls and CustomTemplate

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, rendering-template

I have the following tag:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichLinkField FieldName="Buy_x0020_Now_x0020_Link" runat="server">
```

I want to have a custom rendering template for it as I need to emit the following html

```
<a href="link"><span>Link text</span></a>
```

There seems to be a

```
<CustomTemplate>
```

Tag, but I can't find any reference on the net on how to use it....

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to put the markup you wish to emit within the CustomTemplate tag. Since RichLinkField is a templated control, this is the means for you to specify a different template to the default. If you wish to get the value from the field, I think there's a control which will render the raw value - sorry, I can't remember the name.

Did you try adding stuff into this tag?

Comment: To be honest no, I don't know what tags I need to use to access the data within the tag (ie retrieve URL to embed in my html...). 

Is it my imagination, or are there a variety of ways of doing things in SP when it comes to this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Hideously I ended up writing the links to the page and then hiding them using CSS, I then used Jquery to look up the hidden urls in the page and re-write the link I actually wanted the url to be on.